# LUKS cannot be closed on lvm with lvmcache

Tags: lvm, luks, xfs

I have a CENTOS borgbackup server. All transactions are done over SSH, inside a bind-mounted chroot jail. Most of this detail is probably unnecessary, but I thought a little context might help.

I have an XFS filesystem on top of a LUKS container, on top of a raid1 LVM with two 3TB spinning disks backing the raid array. When the user logs into their chroot jail, pam_exec opens their LUKS container and mounts their backup partition, when they logout, pam_exec unmounts then closes the container. Generally, this has been working just fine. Mounts and unmounts seem. The rootfs is on a sizable SSD. I intended to add an lvmcache to the VG, following the instructions laid out in various places. Since lvmcache is block-based, I figured that it shouldn't matter if the blocks are cleartext or encrypted. I set the cache to writethrough, to ensure the cache was flushed to disk and then attempted to use it. Unfortunately, with lvmcache, it becomes impossible to close the LUKS container, as cryptsetup close fails with the device being listed as busy.  Is this intended behavior? I also tried to force cache flushing and then closing the LUKS container, using the "cleaner" cache policy. This also failed. The LUKS container would only close once the lvmcache was removed from the VG.

Is this intended behavior? I assume the cache is marking the FS as dirty, preventing cryptsetup from closing it, but why is that if lvmcache functions on the blocks? It should not be dirty once the cache is flushed to the disk, right?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Cool setup. I'm having a similar issue: I have a LUKS volume on a partition of an SSD (GPT).  This LUKS volume is a physical volume in LVM.  It is a member of a volume group on which there is a single logical volume, with an ext4 filesystem on it, which is mounted.  I unmounted the filesystem, but can't close the LUKS volume.  fwiw `sudo lvdisplay` shows the logical volume as active, but I don't know enough about it to know if LVM is keeping a lock on the LUKS volume, preventing it from being closed.